# How to get Google Photos tags?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I want to download some photos off Google Photos, but I'd like them to be searchable.

Is there any way of getting the tags Photos assigns to a file? If you search for "black car" or "dog" or "London", you instantly get a list of results - I doubt these are processed on demand, the tags are probably created when you upload something, so they should be available.

But I only found this info for an item:

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems#MediaMetadata

Comment: Looking for the same thing here